# Creating New Roles and Permissions Dynamically in Spring Security 3

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3 in Struts 2 + Spring IOC project.

I have used Custom Filter, Authentication Provider etc. in my Project.

You can see my security.xml here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</global-method-security>

<beans:bean id="expressionHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" >
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="customPermissionEvaluator" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="code.permission.MyCustomPermissionEvaluator" id="customPermissionEvaluator" />

<!-- User Login -->

  <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/user/*" >
<intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/user/showLoginPage.action" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/user/showFirstPage" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_VISIT')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/user/showSecondUserPage" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/user/showThirdUserPage" access="hasRole('ROLE_VISIT')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/user/showFirstPage" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_VISIT')"/>
<form-login login-page="/user/showLoginPage.action" />
<logout invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/"
        logout-url="/user/j_spring_security_logout"/>
<access-denied-handler ref="myAccessDeniedHandler" />

  <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myApplicationFilter"/>
  </http>

    <beans:bean id="myAccessDeniedHandler" class="code.security.MyAccessDeniedHandler" />

    <beans:bean id="myApplicationFilter" class="code.security.MyApplicationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="successHandler"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
      <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/user/showFirstPage">   </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean id="failureHandler"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
      <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/user/showLoginPage.action?login_error=1"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id= "myUserDetailServiceImpl" class="code.security.MyUserDetailServiceImpl">
    </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="code.security.MyAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailServiceImpl"/>

    </beans:bean>

 <!-- User Login Ends -->

 <!-- Admin Login -->

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/admin/*" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/showSecondLogin" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/admin/showSecondLogin"/>
    <logout invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/"
        logout-url="/admin/j_spring_security_logout"/>

    <access-denied-handler ref="myAccessDeniedHandlerForAdmin" />
    <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myApplicationFilterForAdmin"/> 
</http>

<beans:bean id="myAccessDeniedHandlerForAdmin" class="code.security.admin.MyAccessDeniedHandlerForAdmin" />

  <beans:bean id="myApplicationFilterForAdmin" class="code.security.admin.MyApplicationFilterForAdmin">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandlerForAdmin"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandlerForAdmin"/>
   </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="successHandlerForAdmin"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="failureHandlerForAdmin"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
       <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/admin/showSecondLogin?login_error=1"/>
     </beans:bean>

        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProviderForAdmin" />
    <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="myAuthenticationProviderForAdmin" class="code.security.admin.MyAuthenticationProviderForAdmin">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsServiceForAdmin"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id= "userDetailsServiceForAdmin" class="code.security.admin.MyUserDetailsServiceForAdminImpl">
</beans:bean>

 <!-- Admin Login Ends -->

<beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basenames">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>code/security/SecurityMessages</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>            
</beans:bean>
```

Uptill now you can see, url-pattern I have mentioned is hard coded. I wanted to know if there is a way to create new ROLES and PERMISSIONS dynamically, not hard coded.

Like creating new roles and permissions and saving them to database and then accessing from database. I have searched on net, but I am not able to find out how to add new entries to code.

Comment: Do you mean you want dynamic change the access restirction for the urls?

Comment: @Ralph yes. I want to be able to create new roles and then allow them some urls and put restrictions.

Comment: what did you ended up using ?

Comment: you can find the source code of that here https://github.com/springinpractice

Answer (score 46, accepted):

So these are at least two questions:

- How to make the granted authorities/privileges/Roles dynamic?
- How to make the access restriction for the URLs dynamic?

### 1) How to make the granted authorities/privileges/Roles dynamic?

*I will not answer this in great detail, because I believe this theme was discussed often enough.*

The easiest way would be to store the complete user information (login, password and roles) in a database (3 Tables: User, Roles, User2Roles) and use the `JdbcDetailService`. You can configure the two SQL Statements (for authentication and for granting the roles) very nicely in your xml configuration.

But then the user needs to logout and login to get these new Roles. If this is not acceptable, you must also manipulate the Roles of the current logged in user. They are stored in the users session. I guess the easiest way to do that is to add a filter in the spring security filter chain that updates the Roles for every request, if they need to be changed.

### 2) How to make the access restriction for the URLs dynamic?

Here you have at last two ways:

- Hacking into the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` and updating the `securityMetadataSource`, the needed Roles should be stored there. At least you must manipulate the output of the method `DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource#lookupAttributes(String url, String method)`
- The other way would be using other expressions for the `access` attribute instead of `access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"`. Example: `access="isAllowdForUserPages1To3"`. Of course you must create that method. This is called a "custom SpEL expression handler" (If you have the [Spring Security 3 Book](http://web.archive.org/web/20161012152658/http://www.springsecuritybook.com/) it's around page 210. Wish they had chapter numbers!). So what you need to do now is to subclass `WebSecurityExpressionRoot` and introduce a new method `isAllowdForUserPages1To3`. Then you need to subclass `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` and modify the `createEvaluationContext` method so that its first request `StandartEvaluationContext` calls super (you need to cast the result to `StandartEvaluationContext`). Then, replace the `rootObject` in the `StandartEvaluationContext` using your new `CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot` implementation. That's the hard part! Then, you need to replace the `expressionHandler` attribute of the `expressionVoter` (`WebExpressionVoter`) in the xml configuration with your new subclassed `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler`. (This sucks because you first need to write a lot of security configuration explicity as you can't access them directly from the security namespace.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving this thing time and putting efforts. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please tell me any working example of this thing on net ? Because I cannot find proper code.

Comment: @Gurparsad Singh: sorry no, I have studied the book I have mentions and build something similar for the methodExpressions - but it is different and not public. (I guess you are asking for point 2).

Comment: @Dark Drake: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12372555/280244 for an example for a custom web expression.

Answer (score 14):

I would like to supplement Ralph's response about creating custom SpEL expression. His explanations helped very much on my attempt to find the right way to do this, but i think that they need to be extended.

Here is a way on how to create custom SpEL expression:

1) Create custom subclass of ***WebSecurityExpressionRoot*** class. In this subclass create a new method which you will use in expression. For example:

```
public class CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot extends WebSecurityExpressionRoot {

    public CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication a, FilterInvocation fi) {
        super(a, fi);
    }

    public boolean yourCustomMethod() {
        boolean calculatedValue = ...;

        return calculatedValue;

    }
}
```

2) Create custom subclass of ***DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler*** class and override method ***createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi)*** (not createEvaluationContext(...)) in it to return your ***CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot*** instance. For example:

```
@Component(value="customExpressionHandler")
public class CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler {

    @Override
    protected SecurityExpressionRoot createSecurityExpressionRoot(
            Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi) {

        WebSecurityExpressionRoot expressionRoot = new CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, fi);

        return expressionRoot;
}}
```

3)  Define in your spring-security.xml the reference to your expression handler bean

```
<security:http access-denied-page="/error403.jsp" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">
    ...

    <security:expression-handler ref="customExpressionHandler"/>
</security:http>
```

After this, you can use your own custom expression instead of the standard one:

```
<security:authorize access="yourCustomMethod()">
```

Comment: Can you give full tag for <security:http ?

Answer (score 5):

This question has a very straightforward answer. I wonder why you haven't got your answer yet.
There are two things that should be cleared at least:
**First**, you should know that when you are using namespace, automatically some filters will be added to each URL you have written.
**Second**, you should also know that what each filter does.
Back to your question:
As you want to have intercept-url to be dynamically configured, you have to remove those namespaces, and replace them with these filters:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/user/showLoginPage.action" filters="none" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="
        securityContextPersistenceFilter,
        logoutFilter,
        authenticationProcessingFilter,
        exceptionTranslationFilter,
        filterSecurityInterceptor" />
    </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Then you have to inject your own SecurityMetadaSource into FilterSecurityInterceptor. See the following:

```
<bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
    <property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="myFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="myFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource" class="myPackage.MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource">
</bean>
```

But before that, you have to customize 'MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource' first.
This class has to implement the 'DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource'.
As you want to have all roles and URLs in your DB, you have to customize its  ***getAttributes***

Now see the following example of its implementation:

```
public class MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {


    public List<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) {
        FilterInvocation fi = (FilterInvocation) object;
        String url = fi.getRequestUrl();
        List<ConfigAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<ConfigAttribute>();

        attributes = getAttributesByURL(url); //Here Goes Code

        return attributes;
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FilterInvocation.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
}
```

do you see the "Here goes your code" comment? You have to implement that method yourself.
I myself, have a table named URL_ACCESS which contains both URLs and their corresponding roles. After receiving URL from user, I look up into that table and return its related role.

As I'm working exactly on this subject, you may ask any questions... I will always answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Voter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionVoter.html) to dynamically restrict access. Also see [Get Spring Security intercept urls from database or properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315873/get-spring-security-intercept-urls-from-database-or-properties)

Answer (score -1):

1. Create your model (user, role, permissions) and a way to retrieve permissions for a given user;
2. Define your own org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager and configure is (set its providers) to a custom org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider; this last one should return on its authenticate method a Authentication, which should be setted with the GrantedAuthority, in your case, all the permissions for the given user.

The trick in that article is to have roles assigned to users, but, to set the permissions for those roles in the Authentication.authorities object.

For that I advise you to read the API, and see if you can extend some basic ProviderManager and AuthenticationProvider instead of implementing everything. I've done that with LdapAuthenticationProvider setting a custom LdapAuthoritiesPopulator, that would retrieve the correct roles for the user.