# Spring MVC - Checking if User is already logged in via Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC application.**It uses its own custom Login page**. Upon successful login, a 'LOGGED_IN_USER' object is placed in the HTTPSession.

I want to allow only authenticated users to access URLs. I know i can achieve this by using a web filter. But, This part i want to do using Spring Security (my check will remain the same - look for 'LOGGED_IN_USER' object in HTTPSession, if present you are logged in).

*My constraint is i cannot change Login behavior at present - that will not use Spring Security yet.*

**What aspect of Spring Security can i use to achieve this part alone - check if the request is authenticated (from logged in user)?**

Answer (score 127, accepted):

There are at least 4 different ways:

### spring security XML configuration

this is the easiest way

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" ...>
   ...
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/forAll/**" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
```

- @see [Spring Security Reference, Chapter 16.1.1 Common Built-In Expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-common-built-in)
- @see [Spring Security Reference, Chapter 16.2 Web Security Expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-access-web)

### Per @Secured Annotation

requires `<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />`

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RequestMapping(params = "onlyForAdmins")    
public ModelAndView onlyForAdmins() {
    ....
}
```

### Per @PreAuthorize Annotation

requires `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />`

```
 @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
 @RequestMapping(params = "onlyForAuthenticated")
 public ModelAndView onlyForAuthenticatedUsers() {
     ....
 }
```

### Programmatic

```
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null &&
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated() &&
 //when Anonymous Authentication is enabled
 !(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() 
          instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)
```

---

### Custom Expression

If the built-in expressions are not enough, you can extend them. How to extend the SpEL Expressions for the method annotations is discussed for example here:

- [How to create custom methods for use in spring security expression language annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno)
- http://bmchild.blogspot.de/2012/02/creating-custom-regex-spring-security.html

But for the interceptor `<security:intercept-url ... access="myCustomAuthenticatedExpression" />` there is a slightly different approach possible, that does not need to deal with the private class problem. -- *I have only done it for Spring Security 3.0, but I hope it works for 3.1 too.*

1.) you need to create a new class that extends from `WebSecurityExpressionRoot` (Prefix Web is the important part!).

```
public class MyCustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot
         extends WebSecurityExpressionRoot {
     public MyCustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication a,
                 FilterInvocation f) {
          super(a, f);
     }

     /** That method is the one that does the expression evaluation! */
     public boolean myCustomAuthenticatedExpression() {
        return super.request.getSession().getValue("myFlag") != null;
     }
}
```

2.) you need a extend the `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionRootHandler` to have a handler that provides your custom expression root

```
 public class MyCustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler
              extends DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler {

      @Override        
      public EvaluationContext createEvaluationContext(Authentication a,
                FilterInvocation f) {
          StandardEvaluationContext ctx =
                   (StandardEvaluationContext) super.createEvaluationContext(a, f);

           WebSecurityExpressionRoot myRoot =
                    new MyCustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot(a, f);

           ctx.setRootObject(myRoot);
           return ctx;
      }
 }
```

3.) Then you need to register your handler with the voters

```
<security:http use-expressions="true"
 access-decision-manager-ref="httpAccessDecisionManager" ...>
      ...
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/restricted/**"
              access="myCustomAuthenticatedExpression" />         
      ...
</security:http>

<bean id="httpAccessDecisionManager"
      class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <constructor-arg name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="webExpressionVoter" />
            </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="webExpressionVoter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
    <property name="expressionHandler"
              ref="myCustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="myCustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler"
    class="MyCustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

**Spring Security 3.1 Update**

Since Spring Security 3.1 it is a bit easier to implement a custom expression. One does not longer need to sublcass `WebSecurityExpressionHandler` and override `createEvaluationContext`. Instead one sublass `AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation>` or its subclass `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` and override `SecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(final Authentication a, final FilterInvocation f)`.

```
 public class MyCustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler
              extends DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler {

      @Override        
      public SecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(
                Authentication a,
                FilterInvocation f) {
           WebSecurityExpressionRoot myRoot =
                    new MyCustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot(a, f);

           myRoot.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
           myRoot.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
           myRoot.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
           return myRoot;
      }
 }
```

Comment: If we do this: <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />   **Where do i implement the isAuthenticated() method** - i will have to provide the implementation for this since i am handling the sessions completely (not spring security)?

Comment: @Jasper: I have attached two links to spring security reference that list that already build in functions.

Comment: I cannot use the built-in isAuthenticated() function because Spring Security has no way of telling that user is already logged-in as: **Login has been implemented in a custom fashion(not via Spring Security)** - therefore it is impossible for Spring Security to tell if a user is logged-in. What happens is - Upon successful login a flag is put in Session Object indicating that user is logged-in. **i need to check for the presence of that flag in Session object in my custom isAuthenticated() method - how/where can i do that?**

Comment: @Jasper: sorry but I was (and I am still) not able to recognize this requirement from your question.

Comment: @Jasper: I have added a description how to build you own expression. That should help you

Comment: Thanks @Raplh for detailed explanation, i guess writing own Expressions will do the job.

Comment: spelling mistake: SecurityContextHilder => SecurityContextHolder

Comment: Im not sure if the Programmatic version works if you enabled anonymous authentication

Comment: @jpaganz18, correct, one has also to check for `!(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)` - I added this to my answer - thanks

Answer (score 19):

Another solution, you can create class:

```
public class AuthenticationSystem {
    public static boolean isLogged() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return null != authentication && !("anonymousUser").equals(authentication.getName());
    }
    // ...
    // Any another methods, for example, logout
}
```

Then, in controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/promotion")
public final class PromotionController {  
    @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final String root() {
        if (!AuthenticationSystem.isLogged()) return "login"; // or some logic
        // some logic
        return "promotion/index";
    }
}
```

**PS**:

Previous solution has a problem, which explain Peter in comments.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/promotion")
public final class PromotionController {  
    @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final String root(final Principal principal) {
        if (null == principal) return "login"; // or some logic
        // some logic
        return "promotion/index";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the principal is "anonymousUser" when the user is not authenticated

Comment: @peter yes, you are right, my bad, I updated solution.

Comment: Check anonymous authentication via
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;

and
authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken

Answer (score 11):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.authenticated}">Show something</c:when>
  <c:otherwise>Show something else</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks nice one, but it does nt works on JSF app.. should it be different syntax ?

Answer (score 3):

> Many of the authentication providers will create a UserDetails object as the principal.

Another way I found - using spring-security - is to check whether the return value of `Authentication.getPrincipal()` is an instance of `UserDetails`; the method returns `"anonymousUser"`(`String`) by default.

```
boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
   return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a class that extends **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**
and add **authenticated** in matching **URL's**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/User/**").authenticated()
 }
```

you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

I made an endpoint that looks like this:

```
    @GetMapping("/api/authorize")
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
        boolean isLoggedIn = false;
        try {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            isLoggedIn = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isLoggedIn = false;
        }
        return isLoggedIn;
    }
```