# Spring security: is the user logged in or anonymous?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I need a public restful endpoint that can tell me if the current user is logged in or not. Since the user may be authenticated as anonymousUser, I can't just do this:

```
if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated())
...
```

From looking at some other posts, it looks like I might need to do something clumsy like actually look for the anonymous role in granted authorities. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I believe is the simplest solution:

```
// permitAll
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/isAuthorized")
public String isAuthorized(Principal user) {                
    return user != null ? "Y" : "N";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12372555/2387977) (not nice, but works):

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null &&
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated() &&
//when Anonymous Authentication
!(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() 
          instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)
```