# How to interrupt spring security provider chain by condition?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have the following sring security configuration:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="provider1"/>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="provider2"/>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="provider3"/>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="provider4"/>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="provider5"/>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="provider6"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Now I need always return auth fail if now later than 21-00.

I don't want to add same code to each provider.

Is there nicer way?

Comment: You can throw and `AccountStatusException`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303502/multiple-authentication-providers-in-spring-security

Comment: @Evgeni it is correct. but I don't understand why this doesn't work for  **BadCredentialsException**

Comment: @Evgeni I don't see mentions in docs about it

Comment: I don't know. I just found that answer...

Comment: @Evgeni thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical example for an custom security web expression. It is used in the intercept-url pattern instead of an authentication provider

For some details have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12372555/280244), it has some more details about implementing a custom expression

Comment: These providers was written many times ago and I didn't sort out how they works. I just need add additional constraint

Comment: So that make my idea even better, because you do not need to touch the providers, you just need to add the security expression.

Comment: please describe this solution please. I have read your topic but I still don't understand.

Comment: Which classes should I add?