# Spring Boot WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter - Redirect if Login URL is entered

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configure() method

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                    // Redirection after login
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true).permitAll().and().logout()
                    // logout link. Check if there is no conflict with SAML
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout")).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
```

How do I redirect a logged in user to `/home` if user tries to access `/login` ?

PS - My controller code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {"/login"})
public String getIndexPage() {
    return LOGIN_PAGE;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {"/"})
public String getHomePage() {
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

Comment: when the login is successful then redirect the request to  `/home`.

Comment: @MehrajMalik but what if he explicitly tries to access `/login` ? What you have said is already done

Comment: what will happen after login? I mean should not it show the home page or something like that?

Comment: @MehrajMalik yes. It shows a home page. However, If a user is logged in and accesses `/login` , he can see the login page. If I redirect to `/home` , theyll be stuck in infinite loop

Comment: then in login first check if the user already login or not. If yes, then don't do login and just redirect to /home.

Comment: User should not see the login page he is already logged in.

Comment: @MehrajMalik how do I do that ?

Comment: @MehrajMalik I have added the controller code. It is a custom page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC - Checking if User is already logged in via Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371770/spring-mvc-checking-if-user-is-already-logged-in-via-spring-security)