# Spring security - securing method request with hasPermission

Tags: spring, security

The common usage is:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access"ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access"hasPermission("addSomething1") />
```

I haven't seen hasPermission among security expression listed under allowed:

We have only:

authentication; denyAll; hasAnyRole(list of roles); hasIpAddress; isAnonymous() etc.

I am just guessing if "hasPermission" is allowed for method security then it should be also for web-requests too.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yap, it is possible. You just need to switch to expression based evaluation

```
 <security:http use-expressions="true">
```

and provide `PermissionEvaluator` to your expression handler:

```
<security:expression-hanlder ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler" />

<bean id="webSecurityExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler>
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="aclPermissionEvaluator" />
</bean>
```

Of course you need to have `PermissionEvaluator` implementation. You can write your own or you can use `spring-acl` project.

Comment: See my answer at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321696/creating-new-roles-and-permissions-dynamically-in-spring-security-3 it describe how to extend the web security expression root with additional expressions.

Comment: @Aubergine: I just wanted to show where to search for what methods are implemented. Sp the OP hopefully better understand the background.

Answer (score 2):

Pavel Horal already described how to enable expressions in the intercept-url tag (BTW. After enabled it, all access attributes must been written as SpEl expression!)

But there is one thing you need to know: the expressions that are available for the intercept-url tag differ from them that are available for method based security SpEl expressions (like @PreAuthorize). It is because the first are implemented in `WebSecurityExpressoonRoot` but the others are implemented in `MethodSecurityExpressionRoot`.

See my answer at this question stackoverflow.com/questions/8321696/… it describe how to extend the web security expression root with additional expressions.